# How to be tactful when declining CouchSurfing requests for relatively long stays?

Tags: etiquette, couchsurfing

My question is regarding hosting, and how to deal with people who want to stay five or more days. I've hosted a few times now, but pretty specifically only accepted people who want to stay for 1-2 nights: I'm pretty busy, and I do like hosting but it ends up being kind of a burden on my roommates and I (usually the surfer has stuff to do during the day anyway, but you still have to make sure someone's around to let them in the house and such).

However sometimes I get requests from people whose itinerary states that they're looking for a place to stay for five or more days, which is just way too long for us. Often they'll even say in their message they'd be happy just staying for a couple days. However, it seems really awkward to me: what if they come for the first couple days of their trip, they're completely nice and friendly, but then we just have to give them the boot because we're kind of exhausted from managing the whole thing?

I guess one strategy would be to invite them only for the last couple days of their trip, so there's a definite time limit on it, but that seems a little disingenuous to me.

Is there a more tactful way to avoid the awkwardness?

Comment: I think this is a great question, but perhaps not ideally suited for this site, since it's rather open-ended. In any case, my suggestion is to be up-front, and say that you only accept guests for up to X nights. Put it on your profile, and say so directly during your correspondence with the (potential) guests.

Comment: @Flimzy, I don't mean to challenge your authority but it seems like several of the past couchsurfing questions here have been pretty open ended, like http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/16950/what-does-a-couchsurfing-host-expect-from-their-guests and such

Answer (score 10):

To me the 'simplest' solution would be to welcome them to the city, and say you're happy to host, but that you're busy and can really only take people for a couple of days.  Ask them which days suit them the best.

It's up to them whether or not that works.  They may find something more suitable, or they'll be happy to meet you, and then move on, perhaps to another couch and another experience.

It's not rude at all if you explain up front.  You're offering them your couch, after all! :)  Everyone has busy lives and it's understandable that you might be able to put off commitments and activities for a couple of days to host guests from out of town, but that you can't afford to do it (time-wise) for any longer.

Be clear, up front and explain that you're only able to offer two days as you have a lot going on, and they'll be fine with it.

And if on the second day, you decide you're actually loving having them there, there's nothing stopping you from offering an extra day or two!